# NULLIF check for empty string returns empty string with a column name, but NULL with the column value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a database column set to char(255) (yes, CHAR.  Don't ask me why that's how the database was set up) that at present has an empty string with two spaces (i.e. "  ").  Using `NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(column_name)), '')` does NOT work (the output is  [two empty spaces]).  However, using `NULLIF('  ', '')` works correctly and the output is `NULL`.  In other words, the actual column value works correctly, while passing the name of the column returns an incorrect value.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34e49/1

Comment: The reason is because you have not printable characters into column. See http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=164618

Comment: Are you sure they are `char` and not `nchar`?

Comment: @DourHighArch can you explain why that would matter? Whether it's CHAR or NCHAR, LTRIM and RTRIM are going to remove spaces the same way.

Comment: @Aaron, there are more kinds of spaces in `nchar` than in `char` (non-breaking, en, em, figure, thin, et al.) I though they might be treated differently by `Trim` et al. I just tried this and it looks like non-char spaces are converted to '?' so that's not it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the column must have more than just spaces. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(id INT, y CHAR(255));

INSERT #X SELECT 1, ' '
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '  '
UNION ALL SELECT 3, ' ' + CHAR(9);

SELECT id, NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(y)),'') FROM #x;
```

Results:

```
1   NULL
2   NULL
3
```

For a row where this fails, try this:

```
DECLARE @s CHAR(255);
SELECT @s = y FROM #x WHERE id = 3;

DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= DATALENGTH(@s)
BEGIN
  IF ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1)) <> 32
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Position ' + RTRIM(@i) + ' = CHAR(' 
          + RTRIM(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1))) + ')';
  END
  SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

It should tell you what other characters are in there, and where.